# "Property" is not a supported property for BranchUniversalObject - React Native useEffect Warnings on IOS

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, warnings, react-functional-component

I'm building a React Native app using functional components and trying to implement useEffect to generate a URL and a string for a QR Code generator. The code works perfectly, but on IOS, React Native throws multiple warnings for seemingly no reason that all say a version of "Property" is not a supported property for BranchUniversalObject...when they are supported properties.

Can anyone help me understand why it may be throwing these warnings when I implement useEffect? Is there a better way to implement this code as useEffect seems to cause the warnings.

Terminal Error Log:

```
    WARN  "generateShortUrl" is not a supported property for BranchUniversalObject.
     WARN  "_newIdent" is not a supported property for BranchUniversalObject.
     WARN  "registerView" is not a supported property for BranchUniversalObject.
     WARN  "logEvent" is not a supported property for BranchUniversalObject.
     WARN  "release" is not a supported property for BranchUniversalObject.
     WARN  "listOnSpotlight" is not a supported property for BranchUniversalObject.
     WARN  "ident" is not a supported property for BranchUniversalObject.
     WARN  "showShareSheet" is not a supported property for BranchUniversalObject.
     WARN  "_tryFunction" is not a supported property for BranchUniversalObject.
     WARN  "userCompletedAction" is not a supported property for BranchUniversalObject.
```

BranchUniversalObject interface

```
interface BranchUniversalObject {
  ident: string;
  showShareSheet: (
    shareOptions?: BranchShareSheetOptions,
    linkProperties?: BranchLinkProperties,
    controlParams?: BranchLinkControlParams
  ) => Promise<BranchShareSuccess | BranchShareFailure>;
  generateShortUrl: (
    linkProperties?: BranchLinkProperties,
    controlParams?: BranchLinkControlParams
  ) => Promise<{ url: string }>;
  logEvent: (eventName: string, params?: BranchEventParams) => Promise<null>;
  release: () => void;
}
```

QR Code Generation

```
// Creates a QR Code with Branch link parameters
  static createQRCode = async () => {
    let qrCodeSettings = {
      width: 800,
      codeColor: '#6a09d9',
      backgroundColor: '#fac3c3',
      centerLogo: 'https://i.snipboard.io/5PW62T.jpg',
      margin: 1,
      imageFormat: 'PNG',
    };

    let buo = await this.createContentReference();
    let linkProperties = await this.createLinkProperties();
    let controlParams = await this.createControlParameters();

    try {
      let result = await branch.getBranchQRCode(
        qrCodeSettings,
        buo,
        linkProperties,
        controlParams,
      );

      return Promise.resolve('data:image/png;base64,' + result);
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject('BranchWrapper QR Code Err: ' + err);
    }
  };
```

useEffect utilization:

```
// Sets the QR Code string on Page Load
  const [qrCodeString, setQRCodeString] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getQRCodeString() {
      const qrCode = await BranchUtils.createQRCode();
      setQRCodeString(qrCode);
    }
    getQRCodeString();
  });
```

Image:

```
          <Image
            style={styles.qrCodeImage}
            source={{
              uri: qrCodeString,
            }}
          />
```